# WPF animation how to change animation value with stringformat

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to bind a string value with string format.

I have tried many ways but it didn't work.

Could anybody help me to solve this problem?

This is the way I am currently using, but I still want to use `StringFormat`.

How could I do this ?

```
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DotConverter}">
         <Binding Path="LoadingStringShow"/>
         <Binding>
             <Binding.Source>
                <sys:Int16>1</sys:Int16>
             </Binding.Source>
         </Binding>
    </MultiBinding>
</DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
```

Comment: May [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4010782/4610605) help you ?

Comment: StringFormat doesn't apply to `string` values.

Comment: Is this solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to format a string is to do this in code.

You could use [`string.Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) or for C#6's new Feature: ["Interpolated Strings"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings) as shown below to format your `string`.

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get {return $"My Name is {_name}";}
    set 
    {
        _name = value;
        //OnPropertyChanged("Name");
    }
}
```

Your `Binding` will then show: `My Name is <valueofvariable>`

Since your bindings name is `LoadingStringShow` I assume you want to display some kind of loading message.

Maybe this could also help:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LoadingStringShow, StringFormat={}{0}%}" />
```

or

```
<TextBlock TextAlignment="Center">
<TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}%">
         <Binding Path="LoadingStringShow" />
         <Binding Path="CurrentValue" />
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

[Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19278672/4610605)

[Reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18974706/4610605)